# Is it true that $f\ast g\in L^2(G)$, when $f$ and $g$ be in $L^2(G)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, operator-theory, harmonic-analysis

Let $G$ be a unimodular locally compact group and $L^2(G)$ be Banach algebra with convolution product, that is, if $f$ and $g$ be in $L^2(G)$ then $f\ast g$ defined as  following:
$$f\ast g(x)=\int f(y)g(y^{-1}x)dy=\int f(xy)g(y^{-1})dy$$
Is it true that $f\ast g\in L^2(G)$?

For the case that $G$ be a copmact group, it is follows from  invariance of Harr integrals under translations and inversions.

Comment: is your product $f *g$ not just the convolution product on $L^2(G)$? (under which it is closed by definition).

Comment: The convolution $f\ast g$ is defined in question.

Answer (score 1):

The Answer is No. In fact, $L^2(G) \ast L^2 (G) = A(G)$ where $A(G)$ is a [Fourier algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_algebra).

Comment: Even for unimodular groups?

Comment: See [here](http://www.ams.org/notices/201409/rnoti-p1032.pdf) $L^p-$ conjecture